# Child component's Formcontrol values unable to bind on submit

Tags: angular

In my parent component `AddCustomerComponent`, I have used `AddressComponent`, which is child component.
below are the FormControl code for each

**AddCustomerComponent**

```
createFormControl() {
    this.clientRegistrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      orgName: new FormControl(this.customer.orgName, Validators.required),
      panNumber: new FormControl(this.customer.panNumber, Validators.required),
      domainName: new FormControl(
        this.customer.domainName,
        Validators.required
      ),
      priContact: new FormControl(
        this.customer.priContact,
        Validators.required
      ),
      priNumber: new FormControl(this.customer.priNumber, Validators.required),
      priEmail: new FormControl(this.customer.priEmail, Validators.required),
      secContact: new FormControl(this.customer.secContact),
      secNumber: new FormControl(this.customer.secNumber),
      secEmail: new FormControl(this.customer.secEmail),
      address: this.addressForm.getAddressFromGroup(), // I am getting Address Form control
    });
  }
```

**AddressComponent**

```
getAddressFromGroup() {
    this.addressFormFields = this.formBuilder.group({
      addressText: new FormControl(this.addr.addressText),
      pincode: new FormControl(this.addr.pincode),
      country: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: new FormControl(this.country.id),
      }),
      state: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: new FormControl(this.state.id),
      }),
      city: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: new FormControl(this.city.id),
      }),
    });
    return this.addressFormFields;
  }
```

I am fetching the form value of `AddressComponent(Child)` in `AddCustomerComponent(parent)` using

```
@ViewChild(AddressComponent, { static: true }) addressForm: AddressComponent;
```

**It is working fine when adding new records, while adding the records all the values are properly getting and persisted into the database**

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

**Problem is in update,**
I am getting the pre-populated form for the respective user, but when I am submitting the data, I am not getting the values of `AddressComponent`, find the below snapshot

[image]

It is clearly depicted in the screenshot that, all the values are populated in the form, but on submitting the data, entire values of `AddressComponent` is `null`.

**SUBMIT**

```
onClickSubmit(data) {
    console.log("saved data" + JSON.stringify(this.customer));
    this.customer = data;
    console.log('custoemr data', JSON.stringify(this.customer));
    this.customerService.createCustomer(this.customer).subscribe(
      (response) => {

        if (response) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard/customerlist');
          sessionStorage.setItem('registered', 'true');
        }
        console.log(response);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

`data` is nothing but `clientRegistrationForm.value`

[image]

I am unable to figure out the problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show code of update () ?

Comment: Yeah, please see my edits

Comment: `console.log("saved data" + JSON.stringify(this.customer));` what is value of this in browser console when you submit click ?

Comment: Please check the attached snapshot, you will find the values in the console

Comment: so basically, after entering all form value when you click submit button, You will not able to get address form value ?

Comment: Correct, and it is the case when I am trying to update, In edit mode It is working fine, but as you can see the snapshot we have prepopulated form, but still not getting the address values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232758/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-user9634982).

Answer (score 0):

There is chance you might miss to add data to form controls while you are populating the data to the Form, which resulting in giving empty form object while doing Submit.

So make sure that you are adding pre populated data to the appropriate controls.

like

```
this.newForm.controls.addressText.setValue('textValue');
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: that means I need to add values in individual form control, is there any way I can populate the corresponding model and all the values of model become autopopulate

Comment: yeah, You need add separately if you want to access values as formName.value otherwise you can use your corresponding model in `Submit` method.